# Just need my math checked! Integration!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

Let $b \in \mathbb{R}$, and define $f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$f(t)=\begin{cases}t&\text{if $0 \leq t < 1$}\\b-t^2&\text{if $1 \leq t \leq 2$}\end{cases}$$ and let $$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt.$$ $(\text{a})$ Find a formula for $F(x)$.

$(\text{b})$ For what value(s) of $b$ is $F$ differentiable for all $x\in[0,2]$?

---

(a) I got $F(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^3 + bx - b - \frac{1}{6}$.

(b) I got $b = 2$, but this will only be the case if $F(x)$ is correct.

Please let me know how I did!

Comment: Should your answer not be a piecewise function? The result is different depending on whether $x \in [0, 1)$ or $x \in [1, 2]$.

Comment: Your answer for (a) should be in two parts, neither of which are your expression. For (b) $b=2$ looks correct as it is the only value for which $f(x)$ is continuous. However *"this will only be the case if F[x] is correct"* is false.

Comment: So (a) should be something along the lines of 1/2 if x∈[0,1) and (1/3) x^3 + bx - b - 1/6 if x∈[1,2]. The second part may be incorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:  1) find $\int t\ dt$ and $\int (b-t^2)\ dt$  Use them to find $F(x)$.  You are correct that $F(x)$ will have different expressions for $x \in [0,1]$ and $x \in (1,2]$.  It will be continuous at $x=1$, but the slopes on either side will not match unless $b$ is chosen correctly.

Comment: I got 1/2 if x∈[0,1] and (x-3) if x∈(1,2].

Comment: No, it has to depend on $x$. $1/2$ is correct for $x=1$

Comment: (x^2/2) and (-x^3/3 + bx - b +1/3) respectively?

Comment: The first is correct.  The second needs $\frac 12$ added for the integral from $0$ to $1$.  You have the correct integral starting at $1$, but the problem asks to start at $0$.

Comment: That was the only thing I wasn't sure about! Thank you!